# Can't edit a specific table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am very new to Oracle and have been having some issues. I created the database and now I'm on the step where I want to make relations. I created all of my tables exactly the same, but this one table "ORDERS" does not let me edit it after I create it. I tried recreating the table. When I go to edit the table, it always tells me the table does not exist. However if I create another "ORDERS" it tells me that the table already exists. I am also able to add data to it.

Why can't I modify anything about this specific table?

Also, it isn't a permissions issue, I already checked that.

Comment: What tool are you using?  SQL*Plus?  SQL Developer?  Are you logged in as the owner of the ORDERS table?

Comment: SQL-Developer. And yes

Comment: What version of SQL Developer?  I'm not a big SQL Developer user, but I'm poking around, and I found the "Edit Table" dialog.  But, I don't see any problem, and the fact that you said it only happens on this one table, tells me that there's something specific to this table.  Sorry I'm not more help.  It's not the kind of thing that lends itself well to this type of forum for debugging.

Comment: Version 3.2.20.10
Build MAIN-10.20

Its okay, I honestly have no idea why this is happening. Im usually pretty good at debugging little issues like this. But this is just weird...

Comment: I doubt it's a SQL Developer error, but version 4.0.1 is out now, so, it wouldn't hurt to upgrade.

Comment: Does your table show up in the results of "SELECT table_name FROM user_tables"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is the reason, but there exists a probability of that the table has been locked within another session. Check that out if it is shown up as locked and who locks it:

```
SELECT c.owner,
  c.object_name,
  c.object_type,
  b.sid,
  b.serial#,
  b.status,
  b.osuser,
  b.machine
FROM v$locked_object a ,
  v$session b,
  dba_objects c
WHERE b.sid     = a.session_id
AND a.object_id = c.object_id;
```

And if it is shown up as locked, kill the session:

```
 alter system kill session 'sid,serial#';
```